# Question about Vickrey (second price) auction

Tags: game-theory, economics, nash-equilibrium, auction-theory

> Alice and Bob would both like to own the same manuscript. The manuscript is worth 5 million to Alice and worth 3 million to Bob. The present owner of the manuscript proposes the following method of sale, known as a “second-price auction”. Alice and Bob will each simultaneously write down a “bid” for the manuscript. Let $b_A$ be Alice's bid, and let $b_B$ be Bob's bid. The manuscript will go to the person whose bid is highest, and that person will have to pay the other person's bid. If the bids are tied, then a fair coin will be tossed to decide who gets the manuscript, and that person will have to pay the tied bid.
> Everything above is common knowledge to the players (in particular, they know each other's valuations). There are no other bidders. Negative bids are not allowed.
> a)  Write down each player’s payoff function in this game (payoff as a function of bids). Assume the payoff is in millions of USD.
> b)  What are Alice's best responses to $b_B = 2$? What are Alice's best responses to $b_B = 10$?
> c)  Are there any equilibria in which Bob wins the manuscript? Explain very briefly.

---

For a)

I regard payoff function as their expected payoff:

For Alice: $P(b_A \ge b_B)[5-b_B]$

For Bob: $P(b_B\ge b_A)[3-b_A]$

For b)

In either case, the best response for alice is to bid her true value. The reason for this is that when $b_B > 5$, this could make the probability of winning as small as possible; and when $b_B < 5$, this could make the probability of winning as large as possible.

Am I correct?

For c)

I do not know how to answer this one, but seems there is not any equilibrium for this case..

thanks for helping!

Comment: thanks for correcting them!

Answer (score 2):

I think, a) requires the payoff functions given actual bid values, not (yet) probabilities - or rathe with expected values only playing a role with repset to the tie-breakon coin toss. That is for Alice, the payoff is 
$$f_A(b_A,b_B)=\begin{cases}5-b_A&b_A> b_B\\
\frac{5-b_A}2&b_A= b_B\\
0&b_A< b_B\end{cases}$$
and similarly $$f_B(b_A,b_B)=\begin{cases}0&b_A> b_B\\
\frac{3-b_B}2&b_A= b_B
\\3-b_B&b_A<b_B\end{cases}$$

If $b_B=2$, then $b_A=2+\epsilon$ yields $f_A(b_A,b_B)=3-\epsilon$ for Alice (but $b_B=0$ yields only $\frac32$).

If $b_B=10$, then any response $b_A\le 5$ yields $f(b_A,b_B)=0$.

Comment: should it be
5-bB
(5-bB)/2
and 
3-bA
(3-bA)/2

Comment: since the winner only needs to pay the second highest bid for the prize

Comment: So do you mean that the best response for alice when bB = 2
is to bid an amount greater than 2 and less than 5, since any bid between this amount would give alice a payoff of 3?

And when bB = 10, the best response for alice is to bid between 0 and 5, because any bid within this amount would not bring her any payoff right?

Comment: Hagen von eitzen:

Could you explain it more detail about the function for bA > bB?
i do not understand why it is alice value minus 'her' bid but not bob's bid since the winner only needs to pay the second highest bid?

Comment: i do not think this is the answer, but still thanks Hagen!